# android service running activity

Tags: java, android

I made a program to repeat `toast` a message at any time.
Thus, I need my program running on the background.
when I `toast` message at `NickyService.java` ,it can work.
when I `toast` message at `MainActivity.java` ,it cannot work.
What's wrong with my code?

```
//MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //go to NickyService.java
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NickyService.class);
        startService(intent);
        //Toast message right here
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "service started!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

//NickyService .java
public class NickyService extends Service {
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private int check = 10;
    private Timer timer = null;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(NickyService.this, MainActivity.class);
        startService(intent1);

        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the class should be "extends Service".

Answer (score 1):

**First of all**

as you have mentioned in `onStartCommand`

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(NickyService.this, MainActivity.class);
        startService(intent1);
```

here `MainActivity.class` is not a service , it is an Activity

you should use

```
startActivity(intent1);
```

**Second**

Try to make a new class for service like this

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Timer;

/**
 * Created by Jamil on 12/28/2014.
 */
public class NickyService extends Service {
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private int check = 10;
    private Timer timer = null;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }



    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        Toast.makeText(this, "onStartCommand", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Service created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent,  int startId) {
        super.onCreate();

        Toast.makeText(this,"OnStarted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

**Third**

And I think you have forget to put this in the menifest.xml file under Application Tag

```
 <service android:name=".NickyService">
        </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the context you have used.
Use

```
getApplicationContext()
```

instead

```
getBaseContext()
```

inside the Toast message.

Comment: Is there any Exception?

Comment: I think the class should be "extends Service".

Comment: Which class.There is no problem with the extends

Answer (score 0):

@Don Chakkappan this right solution. Use RoboGuice. It is useful for dependency injection.

Sample usage,

```
  public class SampleClass {

    @Inject
    Context context;

    public void doSomethingOnResume() {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Activity has been resumed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

you can inject your necessary object.